# XDocument and load too large XML file on demand

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xml

I did write this code to read a url of xml file:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("url address of xml file here");
        var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("List")
                    select new Event { 
                        Id = Int32.Parse(feed.Element("ID").Value),
                        Name = feed.Element("Name").Value,                            
                        City = feed.Element("City").Value                            
                    };
        return feeds;
```

My problem is that the file is too large (about 40MB) and take too much time to load.
So I am using XmlReader to read xml file but this was not applicable too because I don't know how to load every (for example 10) records in every page on demand and I should read the whole file every time and skip other records to reach appropriate elements, shouldn't I?

```
string XmlFileUrl = @"url address of xml file here";
        using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(XmlFileUrl))
        {     
            bool openItem = false;
            Event item = new Event();

            while (reader.Read())
            {                    
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "List")
                    {
                        item = new Event();
                        openItem = true;
                    }
                    else if (reader.Name == "Name" && openItem)
                        item.Name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        ...
                }
                else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name == "List" && openItem)
                {
                    openItem = false;
                    feeds.Add(item);                                     
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to use Jquery ajax or convert the xml file to json with paging to load just needed data on every page, or any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not so easy to achieve with a XML structure and maybe in this case is `XDocument.Load` not the appropriate method, because AFAIK it always loads the whole document immediately. You can try the [overload with the Stream parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead of URL, and try loading only a part of the the file over the net. Probably you need to write your own loader (that gets only a portion of the file, maybe [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?) and parse the incomplete structure by yourself.

If you can call portions of the XML file controlled by the URI (for example: `http://domain/entries?page=10&take=20` and this call returns a valid XML), then an option would be to use this URL instead of the link to the whole file, something like:

```
var pagedUri = @"http://domain/entries?page=10&take=20";
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load(pagedUri);
var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("List")
            select new Event {
                Id = Int32.Parse(feed.Element("ID").Value),
                Name = feed.Element("Name").Value,
                City = feed.Element("City").Value
            };
return feeds;
```

Have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232397/xdocument-get-part-of-xml-file) where a similar problem is addressed.