# Use XmlReader to just get children

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I have this XML:

```
<root>
  <row>
     <data1>Data</data1>
     <data2>Data</data2>
     <data3>Data
         <subdata>SubData</subdata>
     </data3>
  </row>
</root>
```

and I want to use an `XmlReader` to read only the `<dataX>` elements, without knowing the exact name of `dataX`. I found the `ReadToNextSibling` method, but it needs a name, which I do not know.

Comment: Would XDocument be an option for you?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I thought about it, but this file could be big.

Comment: just curies... could your question be a dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837360/xdocument-and-load-too-large-xml-file-on-demand

Comment: have you considered using the [Skip method of the XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.skip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: You can iterate of each element and check if its name starts with `dataX`. It may not scale well with very big data though.

Comment: @KeithHall that seems to skip all. I have a reasonable result with the `Depth` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath to filter the elements to just the `<dataN>` elements:

<s>/root/row/*[substring(name(), 0,5) = 'data']</s>

```
/root/row/*[starts-with(name(),'data')]
```

However, `XmlReader` cannot use xPath nor wildcards for element names in any of its navigation methods such as `ReadToNextSibling`

---

You could use [`XPathReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950778.aspx), which can be instantiated from an `XmlReader` object, as follows:

```
XPathReader xpr  = new XPathReader("MyXml.xml", "/root/row/*[substring(name(), 0,5) = 'data']"); 

while (xpr.ReadUntilMatch()) {
   Console.WriteLine(xpr.ReadString()); 
}
```

*(You can download `XPathReader` from Microsoft here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22677)*

---

If you don't like the idea of `XPathReader`, you can do the following with `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

foreach (XmlNode item in root.SelectNodes(@"/root/row/*[substring(name(),0,5) = 'data']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

A better `XPath` would actually be:

```
/root/row/*[starts-with(name(),'data')]
```